Orbital magnetization calculation in Quantum ESPRESOO
I want to perform orbital magnetization calculation in Quantum ESPRESOO which is turned on by the tag lorbm = .true.
This method uses berry phase method to calculate the orbital magnetization. Can someone please tell if I need to turn on the spin-orbit coupling? I could not find any articled which explicitly mention this and I am new to this.
